# How to do a specific condition for escaped_fragment with rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, hashbang

I have urls like that `/#!/page1`, I redirect them with :

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=%2F(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^$ /seo/%1.html [QSA,L]
```

So `/#!/page1` read as `/_escaped_fragment_=%2Fpage1` is redirected to `/seo/page1.html`

It's work perfectly however I want to redirect the home `/#!/` to `/seo/index.html` which actually redirect to `/seo/.html`

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=%2F$
 RewriteRule ^$ /seo/index.html [QSA,L]

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=%2F(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^$ /seo/%1.html [QSA,L]
```